# Multidimensional array push manually php codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

```
Array(    

    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [user_id] => 1
        [following_id] => 2
        [type] => user
        [created_on] => 2014-03-01 04:43:57
    )

   [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 15
        [user_id] => 1
        [following_id] => 4
        [type] => user
        [created_on] => 2014-05-27 11:55:17
    )

  )
```

Hi friends,
I have an array of products that I need to create manually next stdclass Object.These array are generated by pushing value.

I'm trying to solve this for more than an hour now, but I don't get it to work. I know it should be easy...but anyway - I don't get it :D

I have working for an hour to create manually next stdclass Object. I want like this. 
How do i create this.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in Advance,
 J

Array(

```
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [user_id] => 1
        [following_id] => 2
        [type] => user
        [created_on] => 2014-03-01 04:43:57
    )

   [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 15
        [user_id] => 1
        [following_id] => 4
        [type] => user
        [created_on] => 2014-05-27 11:55:17
     )
   [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 16
        [user_id] => 1
        [following_id] => 5
        [type] => user
        [created_on] => 2014-05-27 11:55:17
    )

  )
```

Comment: Whats your question ... you just added one more object in the array. What code you are trying, please post here.

Comment: $current = [];
  $current['id'] = '0';
  $current['user_id'] = 1;
  $current['following_id'] = 1;
  $current['type'] = 'user';
  $current['created_on'] = '2014-05-27 11:55:17';
  $current['modified_on'] = '2014-05-27 11:55:17';
  $following[] = $current;  where $following is the main array

Comment: I figured out here is my code $current = new stdClass;
  $current->following_id = $object->id;
  $current->type = 'user';
  array_push($following, $current);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use a function like so :

```
function create($id, $user_id, $following_id, $type, $created_on){
    $obj = new stdClass;
    $obj->id = $id;
    $obj->user_id = $user_id;
    $obj->following_id = $following_id;
    $obj->type = $type;
    $obj->created_on = $created_on;
    return $obj; 
}
```

And assuming your array is `$array`, you add items to it like this:

```
$array[] = create(16, 1, 5, 'user', '2014-05-27 11:55:17');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have figured out. Here is my code : $current = new stdClass;
  $current->following_id = $object->id;
  $current->type = 'user';
  array_push($following, $current);

Comment: You are welcome, if my answer helped, please select it as the right answer :)